# get height window on windows phone 8 javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, height

My problem is on an Application in windows phone 8, I developed with phonegap. 
I try to assign height to body via JS like this: 
$ ('body') css ('height', window.outerHeight).; 
Nokia Lumia 920, it works, but on Nokia 925, I have a white gap at the bottom of the page. 
Therefore, the height is not accurate. 
Do you have any idea?

thank you,

Comment: `html,body { height:100%; overflow-y:auto; }` ? && || a container wrapper inside once you have the body height set to 100%  `#container { height:100%; overflow-y:auto; }`

Comment: have you tried $ ('body') css ('height', $(window).height())

Comment: it's even worse, it gives me not the real height :s